# Show error message after exception handled

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, actions, notices

I have a plugin that updates a user profile, and I want to handle a date exception and show a error message when it fails, but I can't make it work.

Here is part of the class:

```
private function __construct() {
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array($this, "userAdminForm") );
    add_action("personal_options_update", array($this, "updateCustomFields") );
    add_action("edit_user_profile_update", array($this, "updateCustomFields") );
}
public function userAdminForm($user) {
    require_once(ACMFR_PARTIALS."/form.editProfileAdmin.php");
}

public function updateCustomFields($userID) {
    //stuff
    if ( isset($_POST["expirydate"]) ) {
        try {
            $date = new DateTime("FAIL");
            //Do stuff with Date
        }
        catch (Exception $exception) {
            add_action('edit_user_profile', array ($this, 'date_error'));
            //add_action('admin_notices', array ($this, 'date_error'));
        }
    }
    //more stuff
}

public function date_error() {
    echo '<div class="error"><p>Date Format Error</p></div>';
}
```

This is how the plugin works:

When admin enters the User edit profile page (user-edit.php), the plugin shows a partial with some custom fields. When the form is submitted, the updateCustomFields function is called and update the fields.

If the expirydate field has a wrong format, a Exception is raised and I want to show a error.

The problem is that the error message never appears.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how this runs? This might be issue of timing or code running in different page load altogether from when you want notice to appear.

Comment: I edited the question to explain that

Comment: Is there a question here? What isn't working?

Comment: @Dan you are right. The problem is that error message isn't showing

Answer (score 0):

`date_error` seems to be a function of that class, so you'll have to use

```
add_action('edit_user_profile', array($this, 'date_error'));
```

However I am not entirely sure that'll work because I don't know *when* this function is called. It might already be too late to register the hook.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the code using your answer, but still is not working, also I explained more in question how the plugin works

Comment: @stereoactivo Is it your own profile? [`personal_options_update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update) will call the function if you are editing your own profile but [`edit_user_profile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile) will not: "This hook only triggers when a user is viewing another users profile page (not their own)." Add an action for [`show_user_profile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/show_user_profile) if it's your own profile.

Comment: I'm not editing my own profile, I'm editing subscribers profile